# Como modificar um token (spacy - Python)?

Tags: python, token

As bibliotecas importadas:

```
    import spacy
    from spacy.matcher import Matcher
```

O seguinte código adaptado da resposta selecionada deste https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785916/spacy-replace-token  :

```
    nlp=spacy.load("pt_core_news_md")
    doc=nlp("O João gosta da Maria.")

    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    matcher.add("Maria", None, [{"LOWER": "Maria"}])

    def replace_word(orig_text, replacement):
      tok = nlp(orig_text)
      text = ''
      buffer_start = 0
      for _, match_start, _ in matcher(tok):
         if match_start > buffer_start:  
             text += tok[buffer_start: match_start].text + tok[match_start - 1].whitespace_
         text += replacement + tok[match_start].whitespace_  
         buffer_start = match_start + 1
      text += tok[buffer_start:].text
      return text

    print(replace_word("O João gosta da Maria.", "Ana"))
```

Ao imprimir esta última linha, o texto não sofreu de nenhuma alteração (deveria mostrar "O João gosta da Ana"). Será porque estas funções Matcher só funcionam para o inglês e não para "pt_core_news_md"?

P.S.: Na verdade queria que houvesse modificação num token de acordo o seu index do texto onde está, ao invés de ser por condição (igual a determinada string).

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo funciona conforme o esperado

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher


nlp = spacy.load("pt_core_news_md")
doc = nlp("O João gosta da Maria.")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Maria", None, [{"LOWER": "maria"}])


def replace_word(orig_text, replacement):
    tok = nlp(orig_text)
    text = ''
    buffer_start = 0
    for _, match_start, _ in matcher(tok):
        if match_start > buffer_start:
            text += tok[buffer_start: match_start].text + tok[match_start - 1].whitespace_
    text += replacement + tok[match_start].whitespace_
    buffer_start = match_start + 1
    text += tok[buffer_start:].text
    return text


print(replace_word("O João gosta da Maria.", "Ana"))
```

A única modificação frente ao seu código é na linha abaixo:

**de**

```
matcher.add("Maria", None, [{"LOWER": "Maria"}])
```

**para**

```
matcher.add("Maria", None, [{"LOWER": "maria"}])
```

**Nota** LOWER supõe uma palavra toda em caixa baixa, ou seja, letras minúsculas.

**Nota 2** O código também funciona com `pt_core_news_sm` e `pt_core_news_lg`

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!! Ajuda pois! Abraço, Fernando

Comment: Opa! Que bom que ajudou. Se tiver um tempo, leia esse [post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)